# Div rotation increases parent width at some points

Tags: css, border, css-shapes

I have a `div` with a `border-radius`, which is rotated using `keyframes`.
Look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0f6roxz4/3/) in **firefox**.

*To replicate the problem:* let the window size be less than the circle drawn on the page(both in height and width).

Now the problem is that the parent of the rotating div, i.e. `body` in this case, is resizing to a larger width at some points while the rotation is going on.

The same code in Chrome appears like the parent is resized to a greater width and height once and then it becomes stable.

**My question is** (even though I have rotated the circle within parent with `radius = r`): why does the parent width and height increases to greater than r while rotating the div?

---

```css
.circle {
  text-align: center;
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 21px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 8s infinite;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: mymove 8s infinite;
}
body {}@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='circle'>

  rotated
</div>
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/VZ1AK3iB0GRRBpQMo3xP?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem:**

This (odd) behavior is caused because , what you are rotating isn't really a circle, its actually a block(inline block), which has four corners, just a square.

When you define a border radius it is not changed to a circle, instead its borders become rounded, the element is still a square.

Now, **before** you rotate the div(circle), which actually is a square, its parent has a width & height equal its child(by default, since it is the only child of its parent in your case),

i.e say `width=height= r`.

now when you rotate the div, so you rotate a square, and thus when, the square comes diagonally horizontal( or vertical), it gets the maximum height & width.

i.e `diagonal=√2r`, thus, `height = width= √2r` i.e `1.41*r`, this is surely 41% greater than the original radius of the circle.

Now, this is where the parent is increased in width and height.

---

**The solution:**

The solution is quite simple, wrap your circle with a parent, and let it hide the overflow. See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0f6roxz4/4/)

now this does ***not*** actually make the element itself circular, but will remove excessive, space outside the circle, which overflows the parent.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.circle {
  text-align: center;
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 21px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 8s infinite;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: mymove 8s infinite;
}
body {}@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='circle'>

    rotated
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: or... just add display:inline-block to .circle?

Comment: Shouldn't a transformed element be taken out of flow, and then the parent  sizes wouldn't be affected by it ? I am confused about this ...

Comment: @vals.. yes its taken out, but that looks weird when scrollbar is dancing in front of you

Comment: My bad, I was just thinking about the weird horizontal scrollbar movement (when resize), not about the flow of posible elements behind the circle

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez but again, if it is taken out of flow, there shouldn't be any reflow ...